# Why is this div's width stretching across the page in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

If you look at this page in IE7:
[redacted]
If you hover over one of the lines in the chart, you can see the little yellow popup stretches across the page. It shouldn't and doesn't in other browsers. Can somebody tell me why this is happening in IE7?

For what it's worth, I can fix it by specifying a width for that div with CSS. I'm just curious why it's happening 'cause the client will ask!

Comment: Please post your showPopup code. It's difficult to debug without having to reverse-engineer your page.

Comment: The showPopUp code is here: http://webft0tc.moneymate.com/ctRedirector/ctredirector.dll/?jsPopUp@_CADc0a8011c07d1.c0a8013207d1

It's not our code though - it's supplied by a 3rd party vendor (the same group that generates the chart)

Comment: The link you gave requires a login... which you haven't provided :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... firstly - that code is clearly very old. I can tell, because it's sniffing to see whether or not your browser is IE4 (yes, that's a four). Unfortunately, it considers that any IE browser is IE4...

If it detects IE4, it then goes on to set the width of the layer it creates to be the same width as the window - which is why it's so horribly wide for you.

As you've discovered, you should be able to add some CSS to override that width yourself.